# jQuery script written for elements within modal dialog not being invoked

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a jQuery UI modal dialog, and it shows up right. Then, I have some elements inside the dialog, say

```
<div id="test_div">
    Test Click me
</div>
```

When I check for this elements in firebug, it is loaded right. But when I do this:

```
$("#test_div").click(function(){
    alert('I was clicked');
});
```

But this is not being invoked. I am using ruby on rails. I tried putting this code in the application.js, in the form from where the modal dialog is loaded, and in within the modal dialog itself, but neither works. Am I doing anything wrong? Is something needed to be different for modal dialogs? Please help.

Comment: are you binding this click event within the $(document).ready wrapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using .live to bind the events?

So

```
$("#test_div").live("click", function(){
    alert('I was clicked');
});
```

I found that helped sometimes with hidden elements

Also, are you sure the name of your control is #test_div.  Don't know about rails but .Net will alter the name of an element.  For that reason I use the class selector and add a class to my element.

```
<div class="test_div" id="test_div">
    Test Click me
</div>

$(".test_div").live("click", function(){
    alert('I was clicked');
});
```

And wrap the jQuery in;

```
$(function(){
//your code here if you are not already
});
```

Comment: $("#test_div").live("click", function() works. Btw, I have a form on this dialog, and I want it to close when I submit the form, and I can't get it to work either, any suggestions? This is what i am doing:   $("#new_article").live("submit", function(){
   $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
   return false;
  }); If i use $.dialog('close'), the dialog closes, but the post will not return false, hence, a redirect action takes place. I want the return false to work, as well as the modal dialog to close. Anything after return false; is not reached. Thanks.